Flutter Rapid input into TextField
I am using a handheld barcode scanner to scan a barcode. I couldn't get it to work without tracking keyboard input. It now works MOST of the time, but sometimes if I scan #COUNTING-TEST-TEST it will miss letters and result in something like #COUN-T.
Barcode type is Code-128 and scanner is Zebra DS2208
I am using an Amazon Fire Tablet, If I scan on desktop it works perfectly.
Has anyone had success with this?
class CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  String _inputBuffer = ''; // Buffer to accumulate input
  Timer? _bufferTimer; // Timer for clearing buffer

  // Method to manually trigger onSubmitted
  void submit() {
    if (widget.onSubmitted != null) {
      widget.onSubmitted!(widget.controller.text);
      widget.controller.clear();
      _inputBuffer = "";
      widget.focusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }

  KeyEventResult _handleKeyEvent(FocusNode node, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event is KeyDownEvent) {
      final LogicalKeyboardKey logicalKey = event.logicalKey;
      final String key = event.character ?? '';

      // Handle Enter key only when LogicalKeyboardKey.enter is pressed
      if (logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter) { 
        // Call onSubmitted with buffered input
        widget.onSubmitted?.call(_inputBuffer);
        
        // Clear the controller text and input buffer
        widget.controller.clear();
        _inputBuffer = ''; 
        widget.focusNode.requestFocus();
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }

      // Handle Backspace key
      else if (logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
        if (_inputBuffer.isNotEmpty) {
          // Remove the last character from the buffer
          _inputBuffer = _inputBuffer.substring(0, _inputBuffer.length - 1);
          widget.controller.text = _inputBuffer;
        }
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }

      // Handle normal characters: add them to the buffer and update the controller
      else if (key.isNotEmpty && key.length == 1) {
        // Add the character to the buffer and update the controller text
        _inputBuffer += key;
        widget.controller.text = _inputBuffer;  // Reflect the key in the text field
        return KeyEventResult.handled;
      }
    }
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  }

  void _resetBufferTimer() {
    _bufferTimer?.cancel();
    _bufferTimer = Timer(widget.bufferDuration, () {
      setState(() {
        _inputBuffer = ''; // Clear buffer if no input for bufferDuration
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bufferTimer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      focusNode: widget.focusNode,
      onKeyEvent: _handleKeyEvent, // Handle key events here
      child: TextField(
        autocorrect: false,
        autofocus: true,
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        controller: widget.controller,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          prefixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.controller.clear();
              setState(() {
                _inputBuffer = ''; // Clear the buffer as well
              });
            },
          )
        ),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}

I have tried using stream_transform package, queues, buffers. I even tried registering native android edit text if Platform is android, but that came with its own complications, although it was able to read the rapid input very well.

Is there any reason you need to handle key events yourself? Does it still miss input if you input directly in a TextField?

@PurplePolyhedron Yes, it misses input very bad when put input into the Text Field directly. I am going to try Zebra DataWedge today

So I was finally able to get it. I used the flutter_barcode_listener package with a little bit of customization.

    void _handleBarcodeScan(String scannedCode) async {
    if (!widget.focusNode.hasFocus) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      // scannedcode came in with extra whitespace
      _scannedText = scannedCode.trim();
      
      // Scanner configured with enter after scan came in with `a` at the end
      if (_scannedText.endsWith("`a`")) {
        // # was transformed to 3 I needed to only remove the first 3 since 
           that is the only spot # will be
        _scannedText = _scannedText.replaceFirst("3", "#");
      }
      
      // If user manually entered text then often times _scannedText would be 
      // empty so instead I got the text from the widget
      if (_scannedText == "" && widget.controller.text != ""){
        _scannedText = widget.controller.text.toUpperCase();
      }

      // Replace all specific characters as needed
      _scannedText = _scannedText
          .replaceAll("½", "-")
          .replaceAll("``a`", "")
          .replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+"), "") // Remove all spaces, including multiple spaces
          .replaceAll("¡3", "#"); // # would sometimes come in as that weird 
                                  // character as well
    });

    
    widget.controller.clear();
    widget.onBarcodeComplete(_scannedText);
  }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarcodeKeyboardListener(
      bufferDuration: widget.bufferDuration,
      onBarcodeScanned: _handleBarcodeScan,
      child: TextField(
        controller: widget.controller,
        focusNode: widget.focusNode,
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          prefixIcon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: () {
              widget.controller.clear();
              setState(() {
                _scannedText = '';
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        onChanged: _onTextChanged,
        onSubmitted: (value) {
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

